# setup conemu to use visual studio developer command prompt

Tags: conemu

I have just started using ConEmu. I have tried different shells like the default windows `cmd` and the `Powershell` which worked fine. When i tried to add visual studio shell, it didn't work.

I tried "New console dialog". In that i gave this as the path for shell

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

That gave me this error

```
Root process was alive less than 10 seconds, Press Esc or Enter
```

After searching in the internet i even tried an other path as mentioned in a website `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vcvarsall.bat`. That gave me the same error again!

Comment: What is the problem? You tried.. How exactly?

Comment: i have edited my post and stated in it what the problem was @Maximus

Comment: I wonder why it is so hard to find proper arguments for your shell? https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Tasks

Answer (score 17):

```
cmd /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vcvarsall.bat"
```